# Can one develop locally with AWS SAM using a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

Using `sam local start-api` it [doesn't appear](https://github.com/mnapoli/bref/issues/300) to correctly take on my exported $AWS_PROFILE via ~/.aws/credentials.

Nor does it seem to take on the role defined in the [template.yml](https://github.com/unee-t/enterprise/blob/sam/template.yaml).

I have two questions. How do I confirm my PHP project has assumed a role? It's not clear reading https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/

Secondly is it even possible for local development to assume my $AWS_PROFILE? Or am I supposed to code the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in my app?